# Add class on OWL Carousel current item

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, owl-carousel

I'm using OWL Carousel, trying to add class to current item `<div class="item">` when every time slide.

**JS:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
items : 4,
lazyLoad : true,
navigation : true
});

});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="owl-demo" class="owl-carousel">
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl1.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl2.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl3.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
    <div class="item"><img class="lazyOwl" data-src="assets/owl5.jpg" alt="Lazy Owl Image"></div>
</div>
```

**Tried (not working):**

```
$(document).ready(function() {

   $("#owl-demo").owlCarousel({
      items : 4,
      lazyLoad : true,
      navigation : true,
      afterAction: function(elem){
          $(elem).addClass("curent");
      }
   });

});
```

How to add class Current item when every time slide?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

   var carousel = $("#owl-demo");

   carousel.owlCarousel({
   items : 4,
   lazyLoad : true,
   navigation : true,
   afterAction: function(el){
   //remove class active
   this
   .$owlItems
   .removeClass('active')

   //add class active
   this
   .$owlItems //owl internal $ object containing items
   .eq(this.currentItem + 1)
   .addClass('active')    
    } 
    });
});
```

Comment: Hi, thanks, but not works properly, it's add class to previous items.

Comment: Try to substitute .eq(this.currentItem + 1) for .eq(this.currentItem)

Comment: it's add class to previous items only, when first one `(this.currentItem + 1) ` works some time when slider starting first current slide has no class, but second slide has class.